# Always start a section label with 1 even if it's not specified

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to ensure the section number always starts at `1` regardless of whether a section was specified. For example, the following code snippet will generate the subsection number as `0.1`. The objective is to generate `1.1` and this follows through with subsubsections, figure/table numbering, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
% \section{The beginning}
\subsection{Getting Started}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about your document structure. For instance, does the document always contain a `\subsection` directive before it eventually gets to a `\section` directive?

Comment: @Mico: The document could start with a section prior to the subsection *or* starts with a subsection without a section. The fix should work for both scenarios, I hope this makes it clearer!?

Comment: What should happen in the case when there's no `\section` before a `\subsection` directive? Specifically, if and when a `\section` directive *is* encountered after, by assumption, one or more `\subsection` directives have been encountered, what should the value of the `section` counter be: Should it be `2`, since we've already been using `1` as a  prefix for the initial `\subsection` directive(s), or should it be `1`, since that's (by assumption) the first time a `\section` direction is encountered in the document? Please advise.

Comment: You are spot on with the second thought! When there is already a `\section`, it should start with `1`, *not* `2`. However, if there isn't a `\section`, then instead of starting with `0`, it should also start with a `1`.

Answer (score 1):

To start with an arbitrary section level with an arbitrary count you must change the counters of that sections levels (and every higher level, if there are some). The figures and tables can be manipulated in the same way.

Depending to what you want exactly, you can set the counter to a fixed number with `\setcounter` or just add (sum) some number to the counter x times with `\addtocounter`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\addtocounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{5}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{8}

\subsubsection{Getting finished}

Some text

\end{document}
```

This will produce `2.5.9` but adding sections before this settings, the counter will be `3.5.9`, `4.5.9` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

(I rewrote my answer after the OP clarified what he/she wanted to achieve.)

- If there *is* a `\section` directive before the first `\subsection` command, care must be taken to "do nothing special" -- in particular, not to increment the `section` counter.
- Conversely, if there is *no* `\section` directive before the first `\subsection` command, the value of the `section` *counter* is set to `1`. Hence, the number assigned to the first subsection-level header is `1.1` even though no `\section` directive has been executed. By design, this affects not only the numbering of subsections, but that of the captions of `figure` and `table` environments as well. LaTeX sets number of the first "real" section header to `2`.

Observe that the subsection-level header and the two captions in the following screenshot are numbered "1.1" even though no `\section` directive has been issued at that point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\counterwithin{table}{section}  % per the OP's write-up
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{xpatch} % for '\pretocmd' macro
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\ifnum\value{section}=0\stepcounter{section}\fi}{}{}
\pretocmd{\caption}{\ifnum\value{section}=0\stepcounter{section}\fi}{}{}

\begin{document}

%\section{The beginning} % <-- uncomment to revert to standard setup
\subsection{Getting started}
\begin{figure}[h] \caption{First figure} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{First table} \end{table}

\section{The end}
\subsection{Leaving}
\begin{figure}[h] \caption{Second figure} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!] \caption{Second table} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is *almost* correct. In the second case you mentioned, the subsection starts at `1.1` (*i.e.*, the section is `1`). When adding another section, the number should be `2`, not `1`. That way, the sections will always start at `1` regardless of whether `\section` was used prior to `\subsection` or not. I hope this makes the desired output clearer.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily - Please see my revised answer.